# Checkmark not showing up on iPad in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I want the user to be able to select a single row in a `UITableView` and then have that row show the Checkmark accessory. First to check how it looks in the UI, I added the checkmark through the XCode Interface Designer, like this;

[image: Interface Designer]

Ran it on the iPhone X Simulator and it works as expected.

[image: iPhone X Simulator]

But when I run it on the iPad Pro (12.9 inch) (2nd generation) Simulator it doesn't show up.

[image: iPad Pro Simulator]

So I thought that maybe the constraints were the issue, so I tried writing the widths of all the views that could be the problem to the console and they all returned 1024 so that is correct.

When I try setting the checkmark through code I have the same problem.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
Screenshot with red borders on the cells.
[image: Simulator screen]

Comment: check your tableView frame, maybe his width is bigger than you think

Comment: ipad 768/1024 width is 768

Comment: @Sh_Khan iPad Pro 12.9-inch logical resolution is 1024 x 1366 px according to the iOS Design Specifications.

Comment: @ReinierMelian In the view section of the Size inspector it says it has a width of 375 which is locked and changes when I select a different "View as ..." so I don't think that's it, thanks for your reply though.

Comment: in debug mode? @DylanvandenBrink please add `cell.layer.borderWidth = 1` and `cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` and post the screenShot

Comment: @ReinierMelian I posted the screenshot in the original question, looks like the cells/tableview is too wide for the view. So it must be the constraints right? I did fiddle around with them a lot because it is in a scrollview and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: As I first told you @DylanvandenBrink your issue is related to autolayout

Comment: @DylanvandenBrink call for TableView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear instead and let me know if solves your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian Tried that but still didn't fix my issue, so I started from fresh and did the proper constraints and now it's working (still have a different issue, but will open a new question for that), thanks for your trouble.

Comment: @DylanvandenBrink which question is that?

Comment: @ReinierMelian just created it because I wanted to try and fix it myself, no luck so far; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863166/uistackview-within-uiscrollview-is-cut-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is definitely about `constraints` and `Auto Layout`.

- You should set constraints to superView for checkmark : trailing/top/bottom

  Horizontal spacing between the `UILabel` and the `Checkmark`.

  And Edit this last constraint to make it "**Greater or equal**" so that it will eventually grow with bigger screen.
  You will also want to change your **content hugging priority**.
- *`Simpler solution :`* You could also use `UIStackView` in order to proportionally align your label and your checkmark regardless of the screen resolution.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer because I think this is the most helpful for people visiting this question, thanks!