# UIStackView within UIScrollView is cut off

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, uistackview

I'm trying to use a UIStackView within a UIScrollView and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in creating the right constraints because I can't figure out what the problem is.

These are my constraints and ViewController structure.
[image: XCode]

So DestCont is a UIView that has a fixed height and ContentCont should take up the rest of the space, which could be (and is) larger than the screen so it should be able to scroll.

When I test it out in the simulator, I have the following problem. (Resized it so it would fit in the 2MB cap)

[image: Simulator]

The green is the Root View and the black color is the ScrollView, as you can see, it cuts off the bottom portion of the ContentCont view.

**EDIT**

I changed the constraints, removed the fixed UIStackView height, but now, it doesn't show the bottom UIView that's in the UIStackView:
[image: EDIT]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with being fine that just my "ContentCont" UIContainerView will scroll and fixed the switching by using the following tutorial: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot we know that you have set the `StackView`'s height constraint equals to the `self.view`'s height. Then the height is fixed(equal to one screen's height), even though its content view's height may be larger than the screen.

And `UIScrollView` will calculate its `contentSize` depending on its content, so in your case its `contentSize`'s height will always be one screen heigt.

Delete this height constraint, let the `ContentCont`'s content decide the height of it. Also please make sure your constrains in your `ContentCont` are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added a screenshot in my original post with the current issue.

Comment: @DylanvandenBrink Yes, as I said, you should add correct constraints to the elements in the `ContentCont`. Then it can be shown in the stackView.

Comment: I've tried a lot of different combinations for the constraints but can't figure out how to do it correctly, is there a way you could help me with this?

Comment: @DylanvandenBrink Please post your contentcont view.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble, I ended up just being okay with that only the ContentCont UIContainerView will scroll by using the following https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/. I will do this better in the future but for now this is fine.